# unity add object on touched place on screen(rotation)

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, clone

hello guys i have a code that clone an object on the touched area on game and i have a button that change the rotation of the object (the y rotation by 25 deg),i want when i touch the screen that the clone objects will also change by the current rotation of the object. thank you guys

```
private Rigidbody myrigidbody;

void Start()
{
    myrigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
        {
            var pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 10f));
            myrigidbody.MovePosition(new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, 0f));
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Where is your function that changes the rotation?

Comment: the function is when i press the button on the screen the y rotation change by 25 degrees :  public GameObject cube;
    Transform currRotation;
    void Start()
    {

    }
    public void firstAngle() 
    {
        cube.transform.Rotate(0f, 22.5f, 0.0f);
        currRotation = cube.transform;

Comment: If you want the clones to also rotate, just create a manager of all the objects. Whenever a touch is detected, iterate over the objects in the manager's list and rotate all of them accordingly. Another option is to child every single clone to your original object. Now all you need to do is alter the parent's orientation and all the clones as children will follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gonna follow up on TEEBQNE here,

you need a way to reference all cubes if you want all of them to rotate. If you are just testing right now, you can tag all cube objects with a certain name like "cube" and use `FindGameObjectsWithTag()` function to iterate through all of the object types.

So you can change your function from this

```
public void firstAngle() { 
cube.transform.Rotate(0f, 22.5f, 0.0f);
}
```

To this

```
public void firstAngle() { 
foreach (GameObject obj in FindGameObjectsWithTag("cube")){
obj.transform.Rotate(0f, 22.5f, 0.0f);
}
}
```

Of course if you want better conventions as suggested in the comments, you can just replace the FindGameObjectsWithTag with a reference to all the cubes in the scene. This can either be an array, list, etc